# Static inner class fields value (default 0, why?)

Tags: java

The value of k is 0 when I run the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.Inner1 inner1_2 = new A.Inner1();

        System.out.println(inner1_2.getK());
    }
}

class A{
    private int j;
    public static class Inner1{
        private static int k;

        public int getK() {
            System.out.println("value:" + k);
            return k;
        }

        public void setK(int k) {
            this.k = k;
        }
    }
}

value:0
0
```

Jdk 1.8_181

This my comlier error or jvm error? 
I couldn't find an answer

Comment: _The value of k is 0..._ Why are you expecting it not to be zero?

Comment: The `int`  fiield is initialized with a default value of `0` and you never change it, so this is all normal.

Comment: Seems like `k` isn't manually initialized anywhere by you. Whenever you have an `int` as a field, its value is automatically initialized to 0 when it's containing object is instantiated.

Comment: What value would _you_ expect `k` to have? What should the output be in your opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an error, this is expected.

From the language spec, ["Initial Values of Variables"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> - ...
> - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
> - ...

`k` is a class variable, and you don't give it a value explicitly, so you will read its default value.

Answer (score 2):

This is because integers initialize with a default value of zero. In this instance, your `k` variable is never assigned a value so when it's returned the default (0) is returned.

Comment: It is not quite accurate to say integers initialize with a default value, if you use a local integer such as `int j;` and don't initialize it, you will find you will get an unresolved compilation problem when you attempt to use it.  A _class_ variable of type `int` has a default value.

Answer (score 2):

Every [primitive type](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types) has a [default value](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-default-values/) so when you wrote `private static int k;` the value assigned to the integer `k` is set by default to 0, and you never changed that value in your code, therefore it will output 0.

Comment: It's not just primitive types. Reference-typed variables have a default value too, namely `null`.

Comment: @AndyTurner correct and i never said anything about reference types since we're talking here about an ```int``` which is a primitive type, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: My point is that "Every primitive type has a default value" is unnecessarily qualified with "primitive".